# show what's between the component calling elements in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to configure a component to show what's inside his calling elements. How can I do that?

this is my code

```
<app-card>
    <h1>test</h1>
    ...
</app-card>
```

I want the app-card component to take all the html code inside him and show it

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should do the trick.

app-card component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})

export class CardComponent {

}
```